# Django: error when using ModelChoiceField with MongoEngine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have to develop a web interface with Django and I am tryng to display a select list in HTML populated with values obtained from a MongoDB query, but I am facing some problems. I am using MongoEngine.
My forms.py looks like this:

```
class top_hashtags(forms.Form):
    top_hashtags_collection = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Collections.objects.all(), required=True)
```

And in views.py I do this:

```
def index(request):
    form = top_hashtags()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'user':1, 'top_hashtags_form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then, in index.html I have tried to options:

- If I use `{{ top_hashtags.as_p }}` I get a list of Collections object. If I click submit, the form doesn't pass validation.
- If I use something like this:

```html
<td>
  <ul>
    {% for choice in top_hashtags.top_hashtags_collection.field.queryset %}
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="top_hashtags_collection" value="{{choice.collection_name}}" />
      <label for="">{{choice.collection_name}}</label>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</td>
```

It shows the options correctly but I get `AttributeError at /top_hashtags_form 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'model'` when clicking the Submit button.

What I want is just getting user's sellection at server side (obviously).

I have tried many things, but I cannot find the solution. I guess it is something stupid, but I cannot find out. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The last time I checked it was imposible to use django's default forms with mongoengine. [Check this out](https://github.com/jschrewe/django-mongodbforms).

Comment: Thank you very much @sobolevn. Finally, I was able to solve it in another way. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. It might not be the most elegant way of doing it, but it works:

```
class clean_collection(forms.Form):
    OPTIONS = ()
    OPTIONS = list(OPTIONS)
    queryset = Collections.objects.all()
    for q in queryset:
        OPTIONS.append((q.collection_name, q.collection_name))
    OPTIONS = tuple(OPTIONS)
    coleccion = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select,
                                         choices=OPTIONS)
    keyword = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

At my index.py, I just use `{{ form.as_p }}`.

I hope it can help people who faces the same problem.